# Laravel Return Array Of Queries

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have an eloquent model that I want to return the results of more than one query in one call, 
I want it to be in an array:

```
 public static function show_workplace($id) {
      //calculate 3 queries with queryBuilder and return their results in an array
      return [query1 , query2 ,query3] 
}
```

I think that returning an array of query results somehow messes this up. e.g when I return

```
 return query1;
```

it's fine . 
But when I return

```
return [query1,query1]
```

It returns

```
 [{"incrementing":true,"timestamps":true,"exists":true},{"incrementing":true,"timestamps":true,"exists":true}]
```

These fields are not the real fields of the database..!

Any thoughts what I'm doing wrong ? Is it simply bad design to return more than one query in one function , or am I just missing something else?

Comment: Can we see the queries? More than likely, that is the issue.

Comment: This works : return Workplace::find($id);                                      This doesn't : return [Workplace::find($id),Workplace::find($id)].  same exact query .. works alone but doesn't work on an array...it returns the weird result I wrote about

Comment: Do you use `$guarded` in your eloquent models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using toArray on the queries solves it :

```
  return [Workplace::find(13)->toArray(),Workplace::find(13)->toArray()];
```

Would be great if someone would explain what is going on here...the docs are completely vague about this.